# Mount an external write-protected disk with bad geometry on Ubuntu Server 16.04

Tags: partitioning, usb, mount, hard-drive

**I have this problem:**

I can not `mount an external usb disk` formatted in ext3, where the blocks exceed the disk size, bad geometry message.
Unfortunately I can not modify the disk doing the resize and I wanted to know if there is a possibility to mount it just to read some files.

**Here the syslog:**

```
Aug 16 16:34:22 CINE-SERVER4 kernel: [87896.226640] usb 3-11.4.2: new high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
Aug 16 16:34:22 CINE-SERVER4 kernel: [87896.327197] usb 3-11.4.2: New USB device found, idVendor=13fd, idProduct=0840
Aug 16 16:34:22 CINE-SERVER4 kernel: [87896.327202] usb 3-11.4.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Aug 16 16:34:22 CINE-SERVER4 kernel: [87896.327204] usb 3-11.4.2: Product: External
Aug 16 16:34:22 CINE-SERVER4 kernel: [87896.327206] usb 3-11.4.2: Manufacturer: Generic
Aug 16 16:34:22 CINE-SERVER4 kernel: [87896.327208] usb 3-11.4.2: SerialNumber: 333735535054513154202020
Aug 16 16:34:22 CINE-SERVER4 kernel: [87896.327621] usb-storage 3-11.4.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Aug 16 16:34:22 CINE-SERVER4 kernel: [87896.327815] scsi host12: usb-storage 3-11.4.2:1.0
Aug 16 16:34:23 CINE-SERVER4 kernel: [87897.327119] scsi 12:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  External         1.14 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
Aug 16 16:34:23 CINE-SERVER4 kernel: [87897.328017] sd 12:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
Aug 16 16:34:23 CINE-SERVER4 kernel: [87897.328102] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdd] 1953525167 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
Aug 16 16:34:23 CINE-SERVER4 kernel: [87897.328384] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdd] Write Protect is on
Aug 16 16:34:23 CINE-SERVER4 kernel: [87897.328387] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdd] Mode Sense: 23 00 80 00
Aug 16 16:34:23 CINE-SERVER4 kernel: [87897.328662] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdd] No Caching mode page found
Aug 16 16:34:23 CINE-SERVER4 kernel: [87897.329069] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdd] Assuming drive cache: write through
Aug 16 16:34:23 CINE-SERVER4 kernel: [87897.361692]  sdd: sdd1
Aug 16 16:34:23 CINE-SERVER4 kernel: [87897.361700] sdd: p1 size 1953523120 extends beyond EOD, enabling native capacity
Aug 16 16:34:23 CINE-SERVER4 kernel: [87897.363982]  sdd: sdd1
Aug 16 16:34:28 CINE-SERVER4 test-usb-mount.sh[17219]: Error mounting /dev/sdd1: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Error.Failed: Error mounting /dev/sdd1 at /media/root/f4b0f1a8-06ef-4a4e-a595-da8d3a0042f9: Command-line `mount -t "ext3" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid" "/dev/sdd1" "/media/root/f4b0f1a8-06ef-4a4e-a595-da8d3a0042f9"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: /dev/sdd1 is write-protected, mounting read-only
Aug 16 16:34:28 CINE-SERVER4 test-usb-mount.sh[17219]: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdd1,
Aug 16 16:34:28 CINE-SERVER4 test-usb-mount.sh[17219]:        missing codepage or helper program, or other error
Aug 16 16:34:28 CINE-SERVER4 test-usb-mount.sh[17219]:        In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
Aug 16 16:34:28 CINE-SERVER4 test-usb-mount.sh[17219]:        dmesg | tail or so.
Aug 16 16:34:28 CINE-SERVER4 kernel: [87901.632812] EXT4-fs (sdd1): mounting ext3 file system using the ext4 subsystem
Aug 16 16:34:28 CINE-SERVER4 kernel: [87901.633108] EXT4-fs (sdd1): bad geometry: block count 244190390 exceeds size of device (244190389 blocks)
Aug 16 16:34:23 CINE-SERVER4 kernel: [87897.363988] sdd: p1 size 1953523120 extends beyond EOD, truncated
Aug 16 16:34:23 CINE-SERVER4 kernel: [87897.365384] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI disk
```

Comment: Run fsck on the partition/ drive

Comment: @Panther I can not because it is write protect, otherwise I would have used resize2fs, so I was wondering if there is an alternative that allows me to mount it.